# Adding base stack to power BI visual that respond to slicers

Tags: powerbi

Very new to Power BI and am struggling with adding a measure to the y axis .Here is my data:

Baseline column is a measure. I would like to add that as a base for the stacked plot. I can't use calculated column because that doesn't change with slicers. Any help is appreciated.

[image]